# SignalR How to Stop and Start the "Server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I apologize if this has been answered before or for being a stupid question.

I have a web app (.NET MVC c#) that does a number of different functions. I want to add a new function which could utilize websockets

I have looked at SignalR and it looks fine for my use scenario in terms of while it is active, however I don't want it to be active all the time.

It will only be active for a period of time, where an Admin will "allow the function".

Imagine a Business web app which also has a chat option, but the chat option is only allowed during lunch break.

I don't want SignalR running in the background for the 90% of the time it wont be used, so how do I stop it or create a new instance of the Hub?

** EDIT **

Following the answer below (for which I am grateful), I don't think I made the question clear.

I am not sure how the hub "server" is started and stopped. With the abstraction in Visual Studio (ie just add a SignalR class), I cant work out how to dispose of the Hub and then restart it (create an instance of it)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `setTimeout` JavaScript function, on page load, get the current time, calculate the difference until lunch break and make the callback for it another function that starts the hub.

#### Example:

```
<script>
$(function(){
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var lunchTime =  ....
 var timeRemaining = ...
 var lunchEndTime = ...
   
 setTimeout(startHubConnection(),timeRemaining);
 setTimeout(stopHubConnection(),lunchEndTime );

});

function startHubConnection(){
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   //do whatever neccessary here
   
 }); 

function stopHubConnection(){
    $.connection.hub.stop();   
}
</script>
```

On the server side, do an extra needed check in your hub if the time is not within the allowed break

```
Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).serverOrderedDisconnect();
```

Comment: For everyone who votes negatively, just a leave comment, let us know why it is not good solution

Answer (score 0):

You would stop the hub "server" in the same way that you would stop a webAPI server, a WCF server, or any web app running on a web-server; Disable it on the server.

With the abstraction of Visual Studio, it is still running under IIS Express - If you stop your signalR hub "server" from running, when you point your browser to it localhost:12345/signalr/hubs, the page will say something along the lines of "This site can’t be reached".

But why would you want to stop the hub "server" ? Best to let it run... and impose your lunchtime restriction server side.